# How to placing any size of image in the middle of frame

Tags: html, css

I try to set up an image inside the frame.

**STYLE**

```
#wrapper {
        border: 2px solid black;
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        overflow:hidden;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    img{
        position: absolute;
        height:auto;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" alt="our img"  />
</div>
<br>
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/42/6914793-tropical-beach-images.jpg" alt="our img"  />
</div>
```

Is there any way to make sure the image is showing in the middle of frame like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqYGo.jpg) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

Use `transform` to center the image vertically and horizontally

**CSS**

```
img{
        position: absolute;
        height:auto;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/27/)**

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```css
#wrapper {
        border: 2px solid black;
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        overflow:hidden;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align:center;
    }
img{
      max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" alt="our img"  />
</div>
<br>
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/42/6914793-tropical-beach-images.jpg" alt="our img"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will center your `img`:

```
img{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my recommendation:

```
#wrapper {
    text-align:center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}
img{
    display: inline-block;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

And the working jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o0efwd20/